# Arduino Trinket/Attiny85 USB: Possible to read the state of ALL keys?

Tags: c++, arduino, keyboard, usb, attiny

An USB keyboard for example is a shared device within a system. Several keyboards is possible and they share the num, scroll and capslock states. When you press capslock on keyboard #1, keyboard #2 will detect this state.

For an emulated USB keyboard device (using the Trinket library), you can check these values by using:

```
typedef struct { bool caps,num,scroll; } TKeyboardLEDState;
..... 
TKeyboardLEDState usbGetKeyboardLedState()
{
  uint8_t iState = TrinketHidCombo.getLEDstate();
  TKeyboardLEDState tResult;

  tResult.caps = (iState & (1<< KB_LED_CAPS));
  tResult.num = (iState & (1<< KB_LED_NUM));
  tResult.scroll = (iState & (1<< KB_LED_SCROLL));

  return tResult;
}    
.......

void loop()
{
  TKeyboardLEDState recKeybLEDstate = usbGetKeyboardLedState();

  if( recKeybLEDstate.caps )
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

**Question:**

So I wonder if I can do this with ANY key or is this completely impossible? If not, why not? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you press capslock on keyboard #1, keyboard #2 will detect this state.

Thats because the current LED state is transmitted to all keyboards by the OS. But only the LED state is transmitted and not the key state.